# ajax call in beforeCreate does not update data

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get Vue to update value through an api call. I log the searches two times: ones outside the beforeCreate and once inside. Outside it gives the initial value of 'searches', inside the correct, new value.

The main problem is that I don't see the updated values.

```
<div id="app">
        <!-- shows when there are no searches -->
        <p class="text-center" v-if="searches === null">Er werden nog geen zoekopdrachten uitgevoerd.</p>

        <!-- this div gets repeated for every search -->
        <div class="search border border-info rounded p-3 m-3 row" v-for="search in searches">
            <table class="col-6">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info">Zoekwoorden</td>
                    <td v-for="keyword in search.keywords">@{{ keyword }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                    <td class="text-info">Platforms</td>
                    <td v-for="platform in search.platforms">@{{ platform }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info">Gerelateerde zoekwoorden</td>
                    <td v-for="keyword in search.all_keywords">
                        @{{ keyword }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                    <td class="text-info">Locatie</td>
                    <td>Voskenslaan, Gent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info">Datum</td>
                    <td>@{{ search.created_at }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="col-6 text-right">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="search-id text-secondary">#@{{ search.id }}</h3>
                <a :href="'/searches/' + search.id " role="button" class="btn btn-info details-button">Details...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script>
        var $root = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:
                {
                    searches: [
                        { id: 123, keywords: ['sample', 'sample'], platforms: ['sample', 'sample'] },
                        { id: 123, keywords: ['sample', 'sample'], platforms: ['sample', 'sample'] }
                    ]
                },
            beforeCreate: function ()
                {
                    var vm = this;
                    $.get("api/searches", function(data, status){
                        vm.$set(vm,'searches', data);   //zet de waarde van searches gelijk aan de opgehaalde
                        console.log(vm.searches);       //geeft juiste opgehaalde searches
                    });
                }
        });

        console.log($root.searches);    //geeft de initiële twee sample searches
    </script>
```

Comment: Everything seems fine: http://jsbin.com/kefamoq/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to try beforeMount instead of beforeCreate.

[beforeCreate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate) fires before anything in the component is initialied, according to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate):

> Called synchronously immediately after the instance has been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup.

I haven't tested it, but I would be willing to bet this is your issue. Since there are no watchers or data structures initialized, your call to vm.$set(vm,'searches', data) is being overwritten by the component data structure

Whereas [beforeMount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount) is called after data and events/watchers have been initialized:

> Called right before the mounting begins: the render function is about to be called for the first time.

I would probably also just push to the existing array instead of replacing it as such as this (especially if you have populated the search array as in your example):

```
beforeMount: function () {
                var vm = this;
                $.get("api/searches", function(data, status){
                    vm.searches.push(...data); // assuming data is an array
                    console.log(vm.searches); 
                });
},
mounted: function(){
                var vm = this;
                console.log(vm.searches);
},
```

Comment: If his data returns too fast, it really could be it. good catch +1! Just a sidenote: using `push` really is better if the array is big, but it is semantically different from what the OP seems to be trying, so the replacing may be the only way. Though it was worth mentioning

Comment: Your solution seems to work. My 'searches' array is now populated with the data I got from api/searches. The problem is now that the I only see the results in HTML when my get request is faster than Vue.

Comment: For now I have made the ajax call synchronous, which might hold up in this scenario (just loading page content).

Comment: I would recommend synchronicity. You're better off to add a watcher on the searches data parameter and get your logic in there. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: Also, I would recommend adding the vue debugger tools to your browser, assuming you're using firefox or chrome: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools. You can then view the vue stack in your console in the 'vue' tab